# Best foam for copper wiring insulation in split-unit A/C?

Tags: wiring, insulation, air-conditioning, copper-tubing, mini-split

I went to home depot to buy foam insulation for my A/C split unit inverter. It's to cover the copper wire (and other wires) that go from the inside unit (in the room) to the outside unit (in a roof with no shade).

Home Depot has two types of foam: a regular foam for about $2.50 each and a rubber foam for about $6.

What's the difference and which is better?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the length of each reel?  The per-foot price is probably more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The neoprene foam is what I use on the line set , it is easier to shape and a small tube of neoprene glue you can make custom sizes quite easily. The foam stuff is cheap but hard to shape.

Comment: The main difference is that neoprene foam is more flexible and comes in long coils and therefore you can install it on the line set continuously and without seams. It's important to have airtight insulation around the line set to prevent condensation. The R-values are about the same, so that's not why.